# MySQL - How to select all from table "jobs" but exclude results where "bidderid" exists in table "bids" (some ref. is table "bids" has "bidjobid")

Tags: php, mysql

I'm struggling with this MySQL statement, hoping someone can help me out.

I have the folowing tables containing the folowing data.

```
Jobs    |    Bids     |
--------|-------------|
JobID   |   bidManID  |
        |   bidJobID  |
```

**BidJobID** And **JobID** are related to each other.

But I want to select all results from `Jobs` table but ignore the results where "**bidManID**" exists in `Bids` table.

I've searched all over stackoverflow, but can't seem to find the right kind of statement as usually they tend to be "select all from tablea where commonName is the same as commonName in tableb", but this is slightly different as I want to ignore results where something else exists in another table but has a different common denominator.

Comment: isn't it so much easier to do `show create table` and copy paste?

Comment: Do you have an example? I don't think I've used that before. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: "SELECT jobID, jobMemberID, jobCategory, jobDescription, jobBidCount, jobPhoto1FileName, jobPhoto2FileName, jobPhoto3FileName, jobPhoto4FileName, jobFromLatitude, jobFromLongitude, jobToLatitude, jobToLongitude, jobFromPostcode, jobToPostcode FROM jobs WHERE jobID IN (SELECT DISTINCT bidJobID FROM bids WHERE bidManID = ?) ORDER BY jobListTime DESC"

This gets exactly the opposite to the result I want, but I've tried "NOT IN" and it returns no results

Comment: `show create table tablename`. If you want to make a change to the question please edit it instead of posting a comment.

Comment: Try this one `SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE jobID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(bidJobID) FROM bids )`

Comment: I don't want to create a table? I'm wanting to select results from an existing table but only get the results from that table where conditions exist in another table (but which condition isn't the common denominator)

Comment: @user3676945 `show create table jobs`will not create a new table it will only show you the structure of the mentioned table that will be needed to undersatand more the question.

Comment: Hi Amani, that returned less results but still had results from "jobs" where the $bidmanID existed in "bidManID" column within "bids" table. Thanks for your help guys, I'll also look into show create table too. Really appreciate the help

Comment: @user3676945 if you havent yet get your answer then just update your question with the results of  both queries `show create table jobs` and `show create table bids`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for their input and patience.

A friend helped solve this issue and will paste the working statement below for anyone else with a similar issue:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE jobID NOT IN (SELECT bidJobID FROM bids WHERE bidManID = ?)
```

? = $bidmanID (local variable)

Answer (score 0):

You want all jobs with or without bids but not with a given bidManId? (Hope I got this correct this time.)

```
SELECT j.*
FROM jobs j
LEFT JOIN bids b ON b.bidJobId = j.jobId
WHERE b.bidManID != $yourBidManID OR b.bidJobID IS NULL
```

Of course you need to make a correct string out of this.

Comment: This won't work as it has no reference to "bidManID", which would be critical as it's where the $bidmanID equals "bidManID" in "bids" table that I want to exclude from the "jobs" result

Comment: So you want all jobs which a given bidManID has not bidden for? What is bidManID? Do you want all jobs with no bids as well, or only those jobs with bids with different bidManIDs?

Comment: so imagine I select all results from "jobs", then a php (not literaly) example to ignore what I want from "bids" table would be:

if($bidmanID == $row['bidManID']) { 
 // ignore results, because local variable $bidmanID exists in "bids"
}

But I want to do this within the 1 mysql statement.

"select all results from 'jobs' table" but ignore results where $bidmanID(local variable) is equal to bidManID(in 'bids' column).

What they have in common is "jobID" from "jobs" table and "bidJobID" in "bids" table

Comment: I assume that you do not want jobs with no bids. I'll change my answer.

Comment: all jobs but excluding jobs that a bidManID has already bid on. Thanks

Comment: You get me confused again. This is important. Do you want to have jobs WITHOUT bids as well? Because if you only check for not having a certain bidManID, all rows with no bids would be ignored.

Comment: Okay that's great. That selects all the ones where a bidManID "HAS" bid. I want the opposite of this. To exclude these results but select the others. Thanks

Comment: Oh sorry. My mistake.

Comment: I tried doing != and for some reason it returns a lot of results, both not bid on and bid on

Comment: My original answer was a "LEFT JOIN". Now it's only a "JOIN". That should not give results with no bids on it.

Comment: "SELECT j.jobID, j.jobMemberID, j.jobCategory, j.jobDescription, j.jobBidCount, j.jobPhoto1FileName, j.jobPhoto2FileName, j.jobPhoto3FileName, j.jobPhoto4FileName, j.jobFromLatitude, j.jobFromLongitude, j.jobToLatitude, j.jobToLongitude, j.jobFromPostcode, j.jobToPostcode FROM jobs j JOIN bids b ON b.bidJobId = j.jobId WHERE b.bidManID != ?" (using prepared statements, so ? = $vanmanID... it's returning no results - but with just "=" it is returning exactly what I want, just the opposite (all jobs that a bidManID has bid on in "bids", I just need opposite, but for some reason "!=" returns none

Comment: Are there bids with another bidManID (and bidManID must not be NULL). If you run this directly on the database, does it give results?

Comment: Ah right yeah, so this is what is happening (thanks for debug tip). Now, if I view from another bidManID perspective, with !=, it's showing all that have been bidded on (including current bidManID). with just "=" from this other bidManID, it shows only results where bidManID has bidded

Comment: So to re-cap, "!=" is working, but it's not including results that have not been bidded on at all

Comment: Which I'm assuming is "b.bidJobId = j.jobId" as now it's only selecting jobs that exist in "bids". I want to select ALL "jobs", but remove only results where $bidmanID = bidManID in "bids"

Comment: Excuse my impatience, but I was asking for this more than 30 mins ago. Exactly this information. And instead you give lots of pseudo PHP and SQL code. I updated my answer.

Comment: I do apologise. Your new updated statement seems to return all jobs - not excluding the ones where $bidmanID = bidManID in "bids"

Comment: Same result as if I just did "select * from jobs"

Answer (score 0):

A `LEFT JOIN` example has already given and thus here is an example of getting this done using `WHERE NOT EXISTS` like

```
SELECT j.*
FROM jobs j
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM bids  WHERE bidJobId = j.jobId);
```

Comment: This won't work as it has no reference to "bidManID", which would be critical as it's where the $bidmanID equals "bidManID" in "bids" table that I want to exclude from the "jobs" result